# How to add custom cell with custom action to ABPersonViewController?

Tags: customization, contacts, abpersonviewcontroller

i need to add custom cell to the bottom of ABPersonViewController but i don't find how to do that. Can someone tell me how to add custom cell or should i create my custom ABPersonViewController?